# reading file and accessing in haskell (functional programming language)

Tags: haskell

How do i read the following file which has columns of data with header and space or tab delimited, in Haskell 98.

How can i access each element in the input file for example if this 4 by 7 matrix, accessing [1][2] gives YR.

Also how to get the difference in dates in Haskell 98

ID YR MO DA YrM MoM DaM
100 2010 2 20 2010 8 30
110 2010 4 30 2010 9 12
112 2010 8 20 2010 10 20

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a short demo using `readFile`, `(!!)`, `map`, `words`, and `lines`:

```
> f <- readFile "test.txt"
> ((map words $ lines f) !! 0) !! 1
"YR"
```

It's probably not exactly what you want, but should get you on the right track. Keep in mind that this is implementing your solution using lists rather than an array.

---

Forgot to mention, stick your matrix data into a file named test.txt.

Answer (score 4):

For the former, `readFile`, `lines`, and `unfoldr` are your friends. For the latter, see `Data.Time`, which is also well documented.

Comment: Add to this list the function "words", and you should be set to go!  Props @sclv for giving hints and not just posting a solution.

Comment: I am having trouble implementing this, since i never used this language. Can you please give me some code ideas. i need to compare this language to python code, which i did already.

Comment: Daniel's right by the way, you can replace `unfoldr` by `words` and then everything is extremely straightforward. To be really exhaustive, `map` will be useful as well.

Comment: `readFile` gives you back a string. `lines` splits a string into lines (i.e. a list of strings). `words` splits on whitespace rather than just newlines, so it can give you a list of words in a line. Those and many more are documented here: http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-List.html